# ASP.NET Core MVC project: problem with one-to-one relationship primary key and foreign key data

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, foreign-keys, primary-key, data-annotations

I have a problem linking two models of my project so that an affiliate has a unique credential, then I get an error.

Please help me.

[image]

Comment: Hi @bernardo,please share English error message.And try to delete the original database ,then run the command again.

Comment: @Rena Muchas gracias, voy a intentar tu solución y apenas termine te aviso si me funciono, por otra parte con compartir el mensaje de error en ingles a que te referís, ahí compartí el de la migración

Comment: Hi @bernardo,please speak English.